# Como fazer uma consulta que devolva o ultimo registro de cada dia?

Tags: mysql

A duvida é simples, mas infelizmente acho que a resolução não. Tenho uma tabela com vários registros, e preciso realizar uma consulta que me devolva o ultimo registro de cada dia dos últimos 20 dias por exemplo.

```
Exemplo:
|------------ teste ---------------|
|id  | valor1 | data               |
|   1|     12 | 2016-01-01 00:41:00|
|   2|     31 | 2016-01-01 23:00:12|
|   3|     34 | 2016-01-02 00:41:00|
|   4|     63 | 2016-01-03 05:20:21|
|   5|     87 | 2016-01-03 13:51:00|
|   6|     95 | 2016-01-03 14:00:00|
```

A pesquisa deveria retornar o registro [2, 3, 6].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tenta esta solução:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(data) AS ultimo_registo FROM tabela GROUP BY DATE(data)) as Lookup ON Lookup.ultimo_registo = tabela.data
```

Como podes ver, rodei aqui o teste e funcionou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Retornando apenas os últimos 20 registos:

```
SELECT * FROM minha_tabela INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(data1) AS ultimo_registo
FROM minha_tabela GROUP BY DATE(data1)) as Lookup
ON Lookup.ultimo_registo = minha_tabela.data1 ORDER BY data1 DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você precisa formatar para data e, então, agrupar.

```
 SELECT * FROM tabela GROUP BY DATE(data) ORDER BY data DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar:

```
 SELECT max(valor1) FROM tabela GROUP BY DATE(data)
```

Comment: quase daria certo, mas sei que terá algumas ocasiões em que o ultimo registro do dia não terá o maior valor.

Comment: a resposta do @psantos te atende.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você presisará procurar por dias distintos e ordenar pela data ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(data) as dia, t.* FROM tabela t ORDER BY data DESC
```